# Using "../" causes open_basedir restriction error

Tags: php, include, restriction

When I try to include a file like this:

```
include ("../folder/file.php");
```

I get an error:

> Warning: include(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(../folder/file.php) is not within the allowed path(s)

But when I try to include the same file like this:

```
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder/file.php");
```

It works properly.
I appreciate any thoughts to make it work using the first way :)

Regards, ExChill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) should help ;) 
open_basedir settings in php.ini